# KDE contribution

Tags: c++, kde-plasma, open-source

Does it make any sense to contribute to KDE lately, now that all that's "cool" is being moved in the cloud?

It seems like these guys are in need of some contributors and I was wondering whether it's a good C++ code base to learn from and gain experience or it's better to get involved in something that has more momentum ?

Comment: I think KDE has a lot of momentum

Comment: @closers: why close this? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Raj: There's no objective answer and the questions premise is highly subjective.

Comment: @Raj_More, it's a question without a specific answer. It's a request for opinion and conjecture.

Comment: @Lazarus: It may call for opinion based on experience if KDE is good for learning C++, but I don't see how it calls for conjecture.

Comment: @Raj_More, "Does it make sense to contribute to KDE". Any answer to that is conjecture, where is the proof as to whether it "makes sense" to contribute or not? You can express your opinion in support of your conjecture but it's still not evidence or proof.

Answer (score 5):

Desktops will be with us for decades to come. There is a lot of work to do, and I am sure the KDE Project has ample ToDo lists.  So if you want to help, go for it!

Or if you want to be so cutting-edge, contribute to a 'cloud' project. It's still computing, and you'd still be better off to work with something so well organised and put together as KDE.

And I bet there are even KDE/Cloud integration ideas (PIM syncing comes to mind). Did you look?

Just standing here and navel-gazing does not accomplish anything.